# Need to add sequentional data rows

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table with 2 columns. In the first column I have a counter to 30,000. In the second column I would like to add to 2nd column the rows '1-30000' to test for a conversion.

I am trying to make it look like this

```
COL A      Col B
1          1-1
2          1-2    
3          1-3
```

I am a newbie at this and no matter how I try I can get the first row to do my bidding but the Col B starts its row at the end of Col A

Comment: Are you looking for string concatenation? `CONCAT(ColA, '-', ColB)`?

Comment: Can you show your working so far pls.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  your requested output data looks like you just want to add '1-' to ColA

Comment: Is ColB an integer or a string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your RDBMS, but you can try:

```
update table
set colB = colB+'-'+colA
```